# Linked List - Explain the Output of this Code. Ans: [1 2 3 4 3 2 1]

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

What is the output of following function when head node of following linked list is passed as input?
1->2->3->4->5

```
def fun(head):
    if(head==None):
        return
    if head.get_next().get_next()!= None:
        print(head.get_data()," ", end='')
        fun(head.get_next())
    print(head.get_data()," ",end='')
```

Assume head.get_next() --> moving to Next Head.
& head.get_data() --> get the data of current Head.

Comment: That's not the kind of question you usually ask on stackoverflow, the idea is to ask people to help with the problem. Have you tried running that code? If yes and you encountered an issue - please update the question. If you don't understand something about the algorithm - please update the question accordingly.

Comment: I asked for explanation of this output

Answer (score 1):

You can always try writing down each step to understand the output. It must be

[image]

Unless I made a mistake somewhere.

Explanation:

Each step here represents a new [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) frame.

In steps 1, 2, 3 the condition on line 4 is true, so the code prints a value on line 5 and makes a recursive call.
So far we have 1..2..3.. printed to console.

In step 4, however the condition is false. Since 4 is the head, it's next element is 5, and 5 doesn't have a next element.
Now remember as I said before, each step here is a new stack frame. So on step 4 we are in a stack frame 4. If clause is false, so we go to line 7. Head is 4, so we print 4 to console and exit the current frame.

Now we are back in a frame 3 on a line 6. We proceed to line 7, head is 3, so we print 3 and exit the current frame. And so on until we exit the frame 1.

That's where those 4..3..2..1.. came from. They were printed on line 7.

The stack on each step:
[image]

Comment: i understood till  1 2 3 4 but not able to understand last 3 2 1 can you please explain

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.